# Returning Values in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image: Screenshot showing alert even if i select 'female']I have a scenario where there are 4 text boxes and one Radio Button list. If i click the Submit button by leaving all fields it should alert me . I used 4 Required Validator s for text boxes and a java script function for the radio button list.

My mark up language and function is:

```
        function Validate() {

        var radio = document.getElementsByName("rdbGender");                    

        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {

            if (radio[i].checked) {

                return true;

            }
            else
            {

                alert("Choose a Gender");
                return false;

            }
        }    
    }
```

Aspx page is:

```
       <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" Width="50px" OnClientClick= "Validate()"
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

When ever i click the button by leaving fiealds empty, and leaving radio button list with out selecting a item, it is alerting but if i press ok it is executing further. I read in one website that if we write " return true " after alert has been showed and clicking ok it will execute further,,but i wrote "return false" after alert it means untill i check  one radio button it should not execute...Where am i wrong??

```
   Javascript:

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Validate() {

        var checkedVal = false;

        var radio = document.getElementsByName("rdbGender");                    

        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {

            if (radio[i].checked) {

                checkedVal = true;
                return checkedVal;
            }
            else {

                alert('Chhooose gender');
                return checkedVal;
            }


        }


    }

</script>
```

Mark up design:

```
     <tr>
        <td>
            Gender
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbGender" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="MALE">

                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="FEMALE">
            Female
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
   .
   .
   .
   .![enter image description here][2] 
   <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" Width="50px"  ValidationGroup="Star" OnClientClick="return Validate()"
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `return` when calling client function.

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" Width="50px"
 OnClientClick= "return Validate();"
                    OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

For first iteration of for, If first radio button is not checked it would go to else part which is showing alert and returning false. Please implement below code.

```
function Validate() {
        var checkedval=false;
        var radio = document.getElementsByName("rdbGender");                    

        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {

            if (radio[i].checked) {
                    checkedval=true;
                   return checkedval;
            }

        }      
      return checkedval;

}
```

Comment: It worked somehow!!!...If i did not select any radio button it is alerting that s fine , It is working fine with the first radio button item, But if i select the second radio button item still it alerting me!!!

Comment: have u commented if part?

Comment: No..!! Shud i comment it ?

Comment: Where should i alert in function?? after if block??

Comment: should i return checkedval in else block after alert??

Comment: Please study code. for second return checkedval; it will always return false as we have alredy returned true from for loop if any radio button is checked

Comment: still there is problem with 2nd radio button list item, it is alerting me even if i select it!!

Comment: please post ur html code and function. Can u create fiddle

Comment: your code doesnt matches with mine. Please study code first and then implement. My second return checkval is outside for loop

Comment: where i m wrong?? It is chcking in if part whether any of radio button item selected and if not it is executing else part where i implemented 'alert' and returned checkdval parameter which is false..

Comment: thanx it worked!! Sorry if i had trouled u more! i am just now getting my foot wet in Dot net!!! I am really getting confusing with return values...!!!

Comment: Yep no issues, best luck

Answer (score 1):

A function can only have one return value. When `return true` is executed, the function immediately return true and stop going further. Therefore, comment out the return true and try.

```
function Validate() {

        var radio = document.getElementsByName("rdbGender");                    

        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {

            if (radio[i].checked) {

                //return true;  
                //this return true causes the problem.

            }
            else
            {

                alert("Choose a Gender");
                return false;

            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" Width="50px" OnClientClick= "if (!Validate()) return false;"
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" />`